# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-7n^5-6n^4+122n^3-15n^2+7n-2}{21n^5+12n^3-501}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I am stuck with this question, I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I am dividing everything by $n^5$ and getting end result as $\frac{-7}{21}$ but the result in book answer says -$\frac{1}{3}$. Can someone advice? My calculation:
$${\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}}\frac{-7n^5-6n^4+122n^3-15n^2+7n-2}{21n^5+12n^3-501}=\frac{n^5(-7-\frac{6n^4}{n^5}+\frac{122n^3}{n^5}-\frac{15n^2}{n^5}+\frac{7n}{n^5}-\frac{2}{n^5})}{n^5(21+\frac{12n^3}{n^5}-\frac{501}{n^5})}$$

So obviously here $n^5$ cancels out, $\frac{-7}{21}$ stays and all other values go to $0$.

Comment: $\frac{-7}{21} = \frac{-1}{3}$

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, infact we have

$$\frac{-7}{21} = \frac{-7}{7 \times 3}=\frac{-1}{3}$$

Comment: Lol I'm dumb ...